# Invalid Form Body In user_id: Value "user_id" is not snowflake. In discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I am trying to get the username of somebody who sends a message in discord.py with this:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
   print(message.author.id)
   user = await client.fetch_user(message.author)
   await message.channel.send(user)
```

When I run it, nothing is sent on discord and i get the error:

```
Invalid Form Body In user_id: Value "username" is not snowflake
```

So it has gotten the user's username but it wont display it for some reason. Imnot sure what is going on pleasehelp.

12345678901123456778901223445678901223456789012345678901234567890

Comment: Use `await message.channel.send(f"Author username: {str(message.author)}")`.

Answer (score 0):

For you use case you can simply use `message.author.name` to get the author's username.

Moreover, `fetch_user()` required a user ID not a user itself.

So, it should be `await fetch_user(message.author.id)`